# "SQLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,ContentValues);" showing "datatype mismatch" error

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I know basics about SQLite .When i was working on Reverse engineering of SQLite for android development--> Even i have copied most of the code and paste it in mine , my app show error in logcat about data mismatch.

(The error is in setNotes method down)

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



public DatabaseHelper(Context c){
    super(c,"Notes_Database",null,1);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(Note.CREATE_TABLE);

}



@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Note.TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);




}
public long setNotes(String wordv,String reversev){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put("Word",wordv);
    values.put("Reverse",reversev);

    //This below line where the Error occurs.
    long id=db.insert(Note.TABLE_NAME,null,values);//<--


    db.close();
    return id;
}
```

My table name is :

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + "Word" + " TEXT,"
                + "Reverse" + " TEXT"+")";
```

And Here is My Error(That is "***[INSERT INTO notes(Reverse,Word) VALUES (?,?)] datatype mismatch"***) :-(

```
    > 2019-04-14 20:52:05.404 9597-9597/com.example.sqlwithjava E/SQLiteLog: (20) statement aborts at 5: ***[INSERT INTO notes(Reverse,Word) VALUES (?,?)] datatype mismatch***



2019-04-14 20:52:05.406 9597-9597/com.example.sqlwithjava E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting Reverse=gfdhg Word=ghdfg
        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatatypeMismatchException: datatype mismatch (code 20)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1474)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343)
            at com.example.sqlwithjava.DatabaseHelper.setNotes(DatabaseHelper.java:47)
            at com.example.sqlwithjava.MainActivity.ReverseText(MainActivity.java:30)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

And Thanks in advance.

Comment: First try to uninstall the app and rerun.

Comment: what is line `MainActivity.java:30`

Comment: db.setNotes(enteredName,reversedName); MainActivity line 30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Issue

There is only one reason for a datatype mismatch and that is when an attempt is made to insert a non integer value into the **rowid** column or an alias of the **rowid** column. Any other column can store any type of value .

As such column **Reverse** or column **Word** has been defined as an alias of the **rowid** column.

An alias of the **rowid** is defined when you specifically code `column_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` (with or without the AUTOINCREMENT keyword) or an equivalent [as per - ROWIDs and the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid).

Therefore

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
    "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + "Word" + " TEXT,"
            + "Reverse" + " TEXT"+")";
```

**Cannot be what has been used to define the table**.

A common cause of the table not being defined as expected is the frequent mis-conception that the Database Helper's **onCreate** method runs every time the App is run. The **onCreate** will only automatically be run once when the database is created. All subsequent runs will ascertain that the database exists and the **onCreate** method will then not run automatically.

## The Fix

The fix, at least when developing the App, to apply a changed table definition is to either delete the database or to force the onCreate method to run after deleting any tables (otherwise the creation would fail, or if the table definition includes `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ........` that the attempt to create the table would be skipped).

As such the likely fix is to do one of the following :-

- Delete the App's data.
- Uninstall the App.
- or (in your case as the onUpgrade mnethod appears to be fine (drops the table and then calls onCreate)) increase the version number (4th parameter to the SQLiteOpenHelper super call) e.g. change `super(c,"Notes_Database",null,1);` to `super(c,"Notes_Database",null,2);`

After doing one of the above, the App can then be rerun, which should introduce the changed table.

Comment: Thanks mike, After changing CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS and changing version the app worked fine.